# Change region of firebase cloud functions of callable in v2

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Hey so I am trying to upgrade to v2 of firebase cloud functions, but when trying to change the code I noticed that my functions do not have .region anymore like in v1.

Here the v1 version where I could call .region and change it

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

exports.helloWorld = functions.region("europe-west1").https.onCall(() => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", { structuredData: true });

  return { text: "Hello from Firebase!" };
});
```

now I upgraded to v2, but I get:

```
Property 'region' does not exist on type 
'typeof import("/.../node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v2/index")
```

Trying to achieve something like this for v2 of firebase cloud functions any ideas ?

```
import { https, logger } from "firebase-functions/v2";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions/v2";

// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//

const regionalFunctions = functions.region("europe-west1");

exports.helloWorld = regionalFunctions.https.onCall(() => {
  logger.info("Hello logs!", { structuredData: true });

  return { text: "Hello ${process.env.PLANET} and ${process.env.AUDIENCE}" };
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify the `region` in the function's options as shown below:

```
import { onCall } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

export const testFunction = onCall({ region: "..." }, (event) => {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Perfect works like a charm, my issue was that I tried this: onCall({ region: "..." } =>{})

Comment: And don't forget to change the region on client side as well

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547745/how-to-use-httpscallable-on-a-region-other-then-us-central1-for-web

Comment: Make sure to import from `v2`. Took me several hours to figure out why is this not working for me, and turns out the autoimport was for `v1` which does not have the options argument.

Bad:   `import { onCall } from "firebase-functions/v1/https";`
Good: `import { onCall } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";`

Answer (score 2):

You can also set it in the GlobalOptions

```
import { setGlobalOptions } from 'firebase-functions/v2'
setGlobalOptions({ region: 'europe-west3' })
```

this should also work for firestore triggers like onDocumentCreated, onDocumentWritten, etc.

Answer (score 1):

While Dharmaraj's answer works for HTTP Request-based Cloud Functions, do note that there doesn't seem to be a way to do the same for background functions that are run via triggers from sources like Firestore.

The following are the only overloads that I could see of such background functions and none of them contain options to specify the region or other configurations like memory and timeout.

[image]